# HTTP - Should I use Last-Modified as an Etag?

Tags: http, http-headers, etag, last-modified

I can't send Etag header from my site

I'm not sure is it PHP or Nginx issue

but I can send a Last-Modified header

I discovered that I can do something like this to replace etag

```
// response
last-modified: 2929606074

// request
if-modified-since: 2929606074
```

should I use this way?

I also think another way is use the uniqid value (2929606074) minus current timestamp

like: 2929606074 - 1386929153 = 1542676921 and set it as last-modified date

```
// response
last-modified: Tue, 20 Nov 2018 01:22:01 GMT
```

Comment: Last-Modified and if-modified-since require an HTTP-date, not a number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you should not. [HTTP explicitly suggests to send **both** headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.4):

> the preferred behavior for an HTTP/1.1 origin server is to send both a strong entity tag and a Last-Modified value.

`ETag` and `Last-Modified` have a very similar purpose, but the semantic is different. With ETag you identify an entity, with Last-Modified you identify the date of a resource with a resolution of 1 second. Also the client behaviour is different:

- **MUST** use that entity tag
- **SHOULD** use Last-Modified
- **SHOULD** use both